# Central alignment of a container element but maintaining left alignment of its content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a KPI dashboard which has its displays each in their own "tiles", these tiles are of a static `width` and `height` (in the examples provided these are `200px`). The website that these are being placed has the content in a `<div>` with the CSS attributes `margin:auto` and `width:80%`, this has been done to allow users with widescreens to benefit from an increased width of content. What I am after is the tiles to be left aligned as though contained in a table but to be central aligned within the tile container (which takes up the full width of the 80% width body).

I've created a [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/VhYvu/1/), I have previously created solutions which use `JQuery` taking advantage of the `$(window).resize()` handler and programmatically setting the `width` of the tile container however I am hoping that it is possible to do this with pure `CSS` to reduce the `JavaScript` required (I'm already using a lot on the page for `AJAX` and updating displays.

How is it possible to get the required alignment (pictured below) using purely CSS? Additional elements can be added but would prefer to keep the structure as simple as possible.

*Update to Clarify requirements:*

In my examples there are only 3 children, it is possible that the dashboard could have any number for example if you were to have 5 tiles it could be laid out as follows (depending on screen width available and changing of a page resizes):

- 5 on single row
- 4 on the top row 1 on the bottom
- 3 on the top row 2 on the bottom
- 2 rows of 2 tiles and a third with one
- 5 rows of 1 tile

Yes it is possible by explicitly defining the width of each element in pixels, but the width but:

- the `pageBody` element MUST be `width:80%` (not 800px/600px as is common practice), screen real estate used is to be maximised (to a degree) allowing widescreen users to actually see more rather than only showing 600/800px in the middle of their screen.
- the `tileContainer` MUST be centred within the `pageBody` and will "resize" according to the width used by the contained tiles (this CANNOT be explicitly defined in the `CSS` as *n* pixels as different users of the dashboard have different screen sizes and mobile devices make things even more fun). It is possible to do this by changing the width on page resizing using `JQuery` as previously stated but I'm looking for a `CSS` only solution.

  - the `tile` elements are to be left aligned within the `tileContainer`

There are images at the bottom demonstrating required behaviour.

**HTML**

```
3 Children:
<div class='pageBody'>
    <div class='tileContainer'>
        <div class='tile'></div>
        <div class='tile'></div>
        <div class='tile'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pageBody{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}.tileContainer{
    text-align:center; /*Removing this doesn't centre the tiles in their container*/
}.tile{
    background-color:purple;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:5px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**Example:** Left aligned within body

[image: Tiles in a grid format but left aligned within body]

**Example:** Central aligned within body

[image: Tiles centered meaning they are not in a grid layout]

**Example:** Required Alignment

[image: Tiles laid out as though in a grid and centred within the page content]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VhYvu/3/

Comment: Unfortunately that's not centrally aligned within the page body and matches the first image.

Comment: Oh, I'm on a small monitor and couldn't tell the difference.

Answer (score 0):

TylerH was close. 
I just took his jfiddle and modified it slightly. You need to add a width to your second containing div, then you'll be able to use margin auto to center it.

[`Jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/VrFEE/)

Comment: This doesn't center the tiles.

Comment: Sadly that's still not working, you've just moved them slightly off the left side

Comment: You'll need to adjust it to your satisfaction, but that's the basic method you'll want to use to center the elements. Sometimes you can use text-align on the parent also, but that doesn't seem to be working here (don't have time to figure out why.) I made a few adjustments to get it closer.

here http://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/VrFEE/5/

Comment: The idea is to wrap your objects in a centered element tightly defined so that all of the elements within it are "centered" even though they're aligned to the left. The hard part of this of course is keeping the elements side by side. Once you get too confined they'll jump one under the other. Another option would be to use absolute positioning, if you're going to be defining the size of your page with an absolute value.

Comment: Sadly that does not work, the tile container width must be 100% the page placeholder width and the page placeholder width is 80% available space (you've explicitly set the pixel width which doesn't work as required). As I've said before I've got it working previously by adding jQuery to explicitly change the pixel width of the container according to the available width but was hoping to do this without JQuery/JavaScript and certainly without limiting the amount if screen real estate used.

Comment: Alright one more attempt. How does this look? 
http://jsfiddle.net/PhantomDude95/TLF6K/
Actually scratch that, if the second layer of containment has to be 100% I don't think there's a way (with pure css and html) to do that. Why does it need to be 100% exactly? Maybe there's a different way to accomplish this based on needs.